# My Android phone keeps restarting in short cycles

Tags: hardware, reboot, xiaomi, android-one

I have Xiaomi Mi A2 and yesterday when I was using it, it started to restart continuously only loading the android one logo then crashing again. I've tried things like holding down power+voldown and power+volup to reach the safe boot, but the thing is that it restarts again before even loading it. I also though the power on button might be stuck so I've tried to click it through multiple times but does not seem so. I also tried removing SIMs. I did not install anything new in a long time. It discharged itself after multiple hours of repeated restarts.

Anyone has the same experience and would know what to do? Also is there a way to at least wipe the phone contents somehow before returning it to the shop?

Comment: Connect it to a charger. If that changes the restart behavior your battery is near death and has to be replaced.

Comment: your power button stuck or is short circuited/wet

Comment: @Robert I tried that and it just kept restarting with low battery. I suppose battery should be OK then, but thanks for the idea.

Comment: @alecxs Hey I realise now that I indeed splashed a bit of my drink on it but I went and cleaned it and it worked like 20 minutes before this happened. Happened to me already multiple times and never really was an issue so I did not though of that as the spill was little. But I guess it could get somewhere and after further manipulation it could slide deeper into the device. Anyways, I tried to recharge it after like 15 hours so I would expect the water to dry out by now. I will probably try to wait longer and see if anything changes. Thanks for the idea.

Comment: @alecxs Thanks for the info. I might try to put the phone into uncooked rice (wrapped in paper towel) maybe that can speed things up. It should not make it worse at least.

Comment: @alecxs Yeah, but I've read that if not cautious enough the heat can damage the phone. Because I don't really know the materials and specs of the phone, I'll probably stay on the very cautious side on this one. But thanks for the tip.

Comment: @alecxs Hey, thanks for asking. I've tried the rice in closed casket with additional heating (roughly 30-40 celsius) for couple of days and also hair dryer cautiously on the lowest setting (roughly 50 celsius) for like 10-15 minutes, because I was desperate. Sadly still not progress. I think I will try the hair dryer once more for longer period as it clearly did nothing to the phone and if no progress, I will take the phone to shop. I would even try the oven but my oven is currently behaving very unpredictable because its quite old so I'm thinking its probably not worth the risk.